# If and NDSolve Causing Issues

Tags: differential-equations, conditional

I have the code below, which simulates a particle of mass $m$ in a fourth order polynomial potential given an initial conditions $q_0,p_0$. That is to say, I am simulating Hamilton's equations using `NDSolve`.

```
params = {m -> 1.47*^-25, f0 -> 100*^3, ff -> -100*^3};
tf = 200*^-6;
tffreq = tf; (*Final time for ramping of frequency*)
V = α*q^2 + β*q^4 + γ*q;
b = 1*^-4 &;
g = 1*^-23 &;

f = ff + (f0 - ff)*(tffreq - #)/tffreq /. params &;
at = Sign[f[#]]*.5*m*(2*Pi*f[#])^2 /. params &;
a = If[#<tffreq,at[#],at[tffreq]]&;

q0 = -1.72092*^-10;
gradV = D[V, q] /. {γ -> #1, α -> #2, β -> #3, 
     q -> q[t]} &;

{qout, pout} = {q, p} /. 
   NDSolve[{Evaluate[D[q[t], t] == p[t]/m /. params], 
      D[p[t], t] == -1*gradV[g[t], a[t], b[t]], q[0] == q0, 
      p[0] == 0}, {q, p}, {t, 0, tf}][[1]];
Plot[qout[t], {t, 0, tf}]
```

Which gives an incorrect solution for `qout`. However, if I change

```
at = Sign[f[#]]*.5*m*(2*Pi*f[#])^2 /. params &;
a = If[#<tffreq,at[#],at[tffreq]]&;
```

to

```
a = Sign[f[#]]*.5*m*(2*Pi*f[#])^2 /. params &;
```

I find the `qout` that I expect. When I plot `at[t]` and `a[t]` I find that they give the correct results, so I would think that `NDSolve` would behave identically in both instances. Additionally, if I change the conditioning in the `If` to `If[1>0,...]`, I also get the correct results.

For reference, the reason I separate `tf` and `tffreq` is because after a certain time (`tffreq`) I would like `a[t]` to be a constant. My guess is that it is a precision error somewhere, but then I don't know why it would still be plotting the correct `a[t]` even when I condition it.

Here is the correct simulation result, without the conditioning:
[image: Correct Simulation Result]

Here is the incorrect simulation result, with the `If` conditioning:
[image: Incorrect Simulation Result]

Comment: To be more specific, adding `AccuracyGoal -> 16` will resolve the problem.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you.